# Child elements bg color clips to parents border-radius

Tags: parent-child, css

Anyone know of a surefire way to force child elements to stay in the border-radius of their parents?

Here is a js fiddle sample I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/fuego/qCNRZ/

Markup:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        Nah nah nah<br/>
        Nah nah nah<br/>
        Nah nah nah<br/>
        Nah nah nah<br/>
        Nah nah nah<br/>
        Nah nah nah<br/>
        Nah nah nah<br/>
        Nah nah nah<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    border-radius:20px;

}

#inner {
    background:blue;
}
```

I simply want the container to appear blue now, but with the parents rounded edges. I updated the fiddle to reflect.

Comment: I think you need to post a diagram of what you want.

Comment: Sure thing: http://cl.ly/463s090Q412P1u0t2s0t The only place the border-radius is set, is on outer, inner is just fitting snuggly into it. I don't want to have to explicitly set extra border radius to match on inner. It clips!

Comment: No. That is a side effect. I want the inner to clip to the ouster's border-radius.

Answer (score 30):

Based on your example it would suffice to add `overflow:hidden` to your `#outer` element.

Comment: This is the right answer. Without this property, the border radius of a parent is not supposed to clip its children's content by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582176/should-border-radius-clip-the-content/8582304#8582304

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve what you wish with pure css is to add `border-radius` for both `div`.

```
#outer {
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    border-radius:20px;
    height:400px;
}

#inner {
    background:blue;
    border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tZ8AL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Adding "overflow: hidden;" to the outer div will solve your problem. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

just needed margins set http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/83Xrs/2/