# Should border-radius clip the content?

Tags: css

Shouldn't the content of my container be cut off when the container has `border-radius`?

### Sample HTML and CSS:

```css
.progressbar { height: 5px; width: 100px; border-radius: 5px; }
.buffer { width: 25px; height: 5px; background: #999999; }
```

```html
<div class="progressbar">
    <div class="buffer"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see I use `border-radius` on the container (`.progressbar`), [but the content (`.buffer`) goes 'outside' the container](http://jsfiddle.net/u6xkd/). I'm seeing this on Google Chrome.

Is this the expected behavior?

P.S. This isn't about how to fix it, this is about whether it should work like this.

Comment: @CummanderCheckov tnx for notifying me. Let me set it up again. Although all the info *is* in my question (just for this reason) I have updated it.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior?

Yes, as crazy as it sounds, it actually is. Here's why:

The default `overflow` for `<div>` elements (and most other things) is `visible`, and the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html) says this about `overflow: visible`:

> **visible**
>   This value indicates that content is not clipped, i.e., it may be rendered outside the block box.

In turn, [§5.3 Corner clipping](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping) in the Backgrounds and Borders module says:

> A box's backgrounds, but not its border-image, are clipped to the appropriate curve (as determined by ‘background-clip’). **Other effects that clip to the border or padding edge (such as ‘overflow’ other than ‘visible’) also must clip to the curve.** The content of replaced elements is always trimmed to the content edge curve. Also, the area outside the curve of the border edge does not accept mouse events on behalf of the element.

The sentence that I've emphasized specifically mentions that the `overflow` value of the box must be something other than `visible` (that means `auto`, `hidden`, `scroll` and others) in order for the corners to clip its children.

If the box is defined to have visible overflow, which like I said is the default for most visual elements, then the content is not supposed to be clipped at all. And that's why the square corners of `.buffer` go over the rounded corners of `.progressbar`.

Consequently, the simplest way to get `.buffer` to clip within `.progressbar`'s rounded corners is to add an `overflow: hidden` style to `.progressbar`, as shown in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/u6xkd/24).

Comment: Great! Bad question (yeah I know go ask the people who made the spec), but can you think of a reason why replaced elements ARE getting clipped? PS this is a bonus question :)

Comment: @PeeHaa: The content that gets replaced (for example, whatever image is linked in an `<img src="...">`) has to be clipped, since these elements can only contain that replaced content. If not, you won't be able to apply `border-radius` to images, etc.

Answer (score 17):

For anybody wondering what a fix would be. The easiest way would be to edit the css.

In the example given this would be a suitable fix:

```css
.progressbar { height: 5px; width: 100px; border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; }
.buffer { width: 25px; height: 5px; background: #999999; }
```

```html
<div class="progressbar">
    <div class="buffer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Semantically speaking, it's best to simply add a border-radius inherit property to the inner div, hence the new class addition:

```
.buffer {
    border-radius: inherit;
}
```

As a consequence, for others situation, you can preserve the use of overflow: auto if the content overflows your frae and you want to see everything.

Comment: I found this useful for some content which wasn't respecting `overflow: hidden` - much cleaner than setting the border-radius on the children by number, which I had been hoping to avoid.

Comment: This is incorrect. The child content which has the same `border-radius` property will not cover the parent background sometimes. Try it with a blood red parent background, and you'll see it.

Answer (score 4):

The edges and corners of the parent container are covered by quilt elements, so the content of the parent element needs to be cropped, as long as the `overflow` value is set not `visible`, for example:

```css
  .parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This question seems to point to the same defect, apparently this is a bug.

[CSS3 border-radius clipping issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248734/css3-border-radius-clipping-issues)

**Edit**

Eek! BoltClock has mentioned that this is indended so I'll post this other SO question on the topic whilst I also hunt for a spec quote on this.
[How do I prevent an image from overflowing a rounded corner box with CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587814/how-do-i-prevent-an-image-from-overflowing-a-rounded-corner-box-with-css3)

**Specification Link**

Just for reference, I'll stick the relevant link in - but I can't find anything explicit to the example you've given.

[CSS Backgrounds - Rounded Corners](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping)

Comment: The asker of that question misinterpreted the CSS3 spec, and the bug that is referenced concerns an `overflow` value that isn't `visible`, which is not the case here.

Comment: In the spec I've read: `The content of replaced elements is always trimmed to the content edge curve.` Which would mean it should cut off the content. Or am I reading it wrong :P

Comment: @PeeHaa: `div` is not a replaced element, so that bit is irrelevant.

Comment: @BoltClock forgive my ignorance. But what is meant by `replaced elements`?

Comment: @PeeHaa: [An element whose appearance is defined by an external source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements)

Answer (score 2):

This is what the specifications says, so this is the way it should work. But that doesn't mean that Chrome does it like that.

> 5.3. Corner Clipping
>
> A box's backgrounds, but not its border-image, are clipped to the appropriate curve (as determined by ‘background-clip’). Other effects that clip to the border or padding edge (such as ‘overflow’ other than ‘visible’) also must clip to the curve. The content of replaced elements is always trimmed to the content edge curve. Also, the area outside the curve of the border edge does not accept mouse events on behalf of the element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-radius