# How to create not clickable area around object?

Tags: html, css, overflow

It have to be not clickable area around this circle, how do I do that?

```css
.circ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.circ .sub-1,
.circ .sub-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
.circ .sub-1 a,
.circ .sub-2 a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
.sub-2 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circ">
  <div class="sub-1">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-2">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks people so much!

Comment: Actually, your code works, in Edge/Firefox but not Chrome, which has a history with clipping and border radius: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101743/inconsistent-selectable-area-of-elements-with-border-radius

Comment: Checking up on older answers and found this. I updated my answer with a sample that does work on Chrome too, rotated included, so if you could review it, and if it works upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

It should work as is, tested in Edge and Firefox and both work, though Chrome (and maybe other WebKit based browsers too) had an issue earlier with not [clipping border radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101743/inconsistent-selectable-area-of-elements-with-border-radius), and in your case they appear still does.

Here is a workaround, a simplified version of yours that does work, rotated 30 degrees.

The trick to make it work on Chrome (assume all WebKit based browsers) is:

- to not use `position` on the div `circ` and anchors `a`
- move the 2:nd anchor using margin instead of `position`

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(30deg);
}
.circ {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circ a {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
.circ a + a {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circ">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we have the situation that this circle have a lot of rotation transformation. And there were number of child from 2 to 6 inside. 
So we don't even now were to use  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
because it changes dynamically

Comment: @ІвченкоДима That info was crucial, and since you didn't post that in your initial question, you'll need to show exactly where this is going. As I commented above, Chrome has issues but there might be a way, based on the end result you are after