# How do I make border-radius in radio buttons?

Tags: html, css

How do I make `border-radius` in radio buttons?
How do I apply `border-radius` to the `box` class?

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item_active {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item_active item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

I set it to `50px`, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/xs17zk3c/16/

Comment: You need to put radius to the item class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should border-radius clip the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582176/should-border-radius-clip-the-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add overflow hidden to .box class, so that the border radius cuts the underlaying content.

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.item_active {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item_active item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```